# I need help getting the right command

Tags: salt-stack

I have a list of minions I need to know the OS I don't know the command to use my list. I see people using this command `salt '*' grains.item os` but I need something like this: `salt "my list" grains.item OS`

Answer (score 0):

It depends what kind of list you mean. There are multiple ways to [target different minions](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/targeting/).

```sh
salt -E 'minion1|minion2|minion3' grains.item os
```